# Is the word "only" in the correct place in the sentence: "Speaking naturally is really only a skill you can develop through practice."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, emphasis

The location of the word **"only"** is somewhat blurry for me. Should it come before or after what it refers to. In the case of **"staff only"**, it is after the word it refers to, but in the case of **"This is the only food that is available."** it comes before the word it refers to.

Here is another sentenc whwere I could not quite be sure about its location.

**Speaking naturally is really only a skill you can develop through practice.**

As you can see, the word **"only"** is referring to ****"through practice."** So, I wonder why it was not placed just before or after it. **"Would it not be better, if the word **"only"** was placed in one of the following ways:

1- "Speaking naturally is really a skill you can develop **only** through practice." (It comes before **"through practice"**)

2- "Speaking naturally is really a skill you can develop through practice, only." It comes after **"through practice"**)

Answer (score 1):

1 - * "Speaking naturally is really a skill you can develop **only** through practice." (It comes before "through practice")

2 - * Speaking naturally is really a skill you can develop through practice  **only**. In this

Putting **only at the end** for that utterance does not change its meaning.

Adverbs can be placed before or after a verb: He often works late. He works late often.

3 - * Speaking naturally **is** really **only a skill** you can develop through practice.

**only** in sentence 1 & 2 is an **adverb**. It means solely or exclusively. It modifies develop. It tells us **how** you can develop the skill.

**only** in sentence 3 is also an adverb: *placed after *be* as a main verb* in the sentence.

4 - * This is the only food available.

**only** there is an adjective.

Cambridge has an excellent page on only: [only](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/only)

Its main points are:

> **Only: position** As an adjective, we use only in front of a noun or one, or before another adjective or a number: [see the examples via the link below]
>
> **We can use only as an adverb in different positions, depending on its focus.** If the subject is the focus, we put only in front
> position:
>
> Only Jason knows where the key is kept.
>
> Only a very small bed will fit in this room.
>
> If the focus is on another part of the sentence, we usually put only
> in the normal mid position for adverbs (between the subject and the
> main verb, or after the modal verb or first auxiliary verb, **or after
> be as a main verb**):

> I only go home once a month. (between subject and main verb)
> She had
> only arrived at midnight the night before. (after the first auxiliary
> verb)
> She’s only sixteen.
> (after be as a main verb)

[All bolding mine.]